# Django 'User' object has no attribute 'Goals'

Tags: python, html, django

I have created a function that can save multiple goals per one user and display them in an html file. The issue is once I logout, I cannot log back in with the same user as I get the error `User` object has no attribute `Goals`, even though it is saved in the database. My question is what is causing this error, the references to goals in my view maybe, and what is a potential solution? Thank you!

models.py

```
class Goals(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    goal = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    instrument = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=instrument_list, blank=True)
    goal_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Goals


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_goals(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Goals.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_goals(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.Goals.save()


class GoalsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Goals
        exclude = ('user',)
```

views.py

```
def goal_creation(request):
    form = GoalsForm()
    cur_goals = Goals.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = GoalsForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            goals = form.save(commit=False)
            goals.user = request.user
            goals.save()
            cur_goals = Goals.objects.filter(user=request.user)
            return redirect('/student/goal-progress')

        else:
            form = GoalsForm()

    context = {'form' : form, 'goals': cur_goals}
    return render(request, 'student/goal_creation.html', context)
```

Comment: Your `__str__` is not working, and change `instance.Goals.save()` to `instance.goals.save()` and you don't need to define `cur_goals = Goals.objects.filter(user=request.user)` after `goals.save()`

Answer (score 3):

You have two issues:

1. You can't access child instances using `instance.Goals`; you should use `instance.goals_set`.
2. You can't `save` a queryset. You should save `Goals` instances one by one, i.e.

```
for goal in instance.goals_set.all():
    goal.save()
```

That being said, I recommend you to rename your `Goals` class to `Goal` as it will create confusion with Django's naming conventions. It also makes sense because each row represents a single `goal`.

Comment: Do i need to change my def __str__ and def create_user_goals because they use the Goals object, instead of goal? Wondering the same thing for the goals items in my views as well

Comment: That `__str__` method does not make sense as it already applies to a `Goals` instance anyway, but yes, you should remove that too. `create_user_goals` looks fine as it creates a new model instance using the `Goals` class.

Comment: Also, I am getting the error, 'User' object has no attribute 'goals', when I try to log in. The issue is still present for some reason

Comment: Commerce You should consider accepting the answer if that fix's your problem as I did here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54405412/increment-object-count-using-same-form in your previous question.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `related_name='goals'` to user field definition of Goals class:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='goals', null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then, you should be able to access this property on the user's object:
`user_instance.goals.all()`.

Migration might be required.

Although this is not directly related to the issue, I think that it's better to name the model class in singular form "Goal", it will be consistent with other model's names (model represents one object=one row) and avoid ambiguity in automatic pluralization.